# PostgreSQL group by to get unique values and add a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have two tables like this:

**Table A**

| id | sum_value | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | Paris |
| 1 | 4 | Paris |
| 2 | 10 | Berlin |
| 3 | 68 | Milan |
| 4 | 51 | London |
| 3 | 2 | Milan |

**Table B**

| id | city | geom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paris | MULTIPOLYGON(XXX) |
| 2 | Berlin | MULTIPOLYGON(XXX) |
| 3 | Milan | MULTIPOLYGON(XXX) |
| 4 | London | MULTIPOLYGON(XXX) |

I would like to make a selection of a sum of a field (`sum_value`) for all cities and add the city geometry to it. I use a group by to have the cities as unique values with the sum. This is possible with the following code:

```
SELECT SUM(tablea.sum_value), tableb.city
FROM tablea, tableb
WHERE tablea.id = tableb.id
GROUP BY  tableb.city
```

So I get something like this:

| sum | city |
| --- | --- |
| 18 | Paris |
| 10 | Berlin |
| 70 | Milan |
| 51 | London |

To add the city geometry I tried following but I does not give the expected result. The city values are not unique anymore and the SUM does not work.

```
SELECT SUM(tablea.sum_value), tableb.city, tableb.geom
FROM tablea, tableb
WHERE tablea.id = tableb.id
GROUP BY  tableb.city, tableb.geom
```

So I get this:

| sum_value | city | geom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | Paris | MULTIPOLYGON(XXX) |
| 4 | Paris | MULTIPOLYGON(XXX) |
| 10 | Berlin | MULTIPOLYGON(XXX) |
| 68 | Milan | MULTIPOLYGON(XXX) |
| 51 | London | MULTIPOLYGON(XXX) |
| 2 | Milan | MULTIPOLYGON(XXX) |

But I want this :

| sum | city | geom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | Paris | MULTIPOLYGON(XXX) |
| 10 | Berlin | MULTIPOLYGON(XXX) |
| 70 | Milan | MULTIPOLYGON(XXX) |
| 51 | London | MULTIPOLYGON(XXX) |

How can I add the city geometry and still have unique city values and execute the SUM?

**Important note : the geometries are multipolygons**

I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: 1) Please update your answer with the version and type of SQL you are using e.g. SQL server 2017, MySQL 8, SQLLite, Posgres 8 etc 2) Did you really search the SO site before posting your question? There are so many questions with answers for aggregations, getting unique values without duplicates, and adding a new column.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question. Yes I have tried without success. This is my last hope.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the data, I imagine this could be happening because there are multiple examples of geometry per city, but I also agree with Francisco in not using:

```
FROM tablea, tableb
```

This is a CROSS JOIN which I am not sure is intended here if you are simply trying to join over the geometry field.

```
SELECT
   SUM(tablea.sum)
   , tableb.city
   , tableb.geom
FROM tablea
   JOIN tableb 
      ON tablea.id = tableb.id
GROUP BY
   tableb.city
   , tableb.geom
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your problem is more suitable to use INNER JOIN.
Exemple:

```
SELECT SUM(tablea.sum), tableb.city, tableb.geom
FROM tablea INNER JOIN tableb 
ON tablea.id = tableb.id
```

Comment: Thank you. If I try this I get the following error: `SQL Error 42803: ERROR: column 'tableb.city' must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some of the cities does not have the same geom value as the others. Try this one to see the differences

```
SELECT SUM(tablea.sum), tableb.city, ST_X(tableb.geom), ST_Y(tableb.geom)
FROM tablea INNER JOIN tableb 
ON tablea.id = tableb.id
GROUP BY tableb.city, ST_X(tableb.geom), ST_Y(tableb.geom)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is not working since the geometry are multipolygons and not points

Answer (score 0):

This ensures that the city is unique, and if there are more than one geometry per city, it will select only one:

```
SELECT  tableb.city, SUM(tablea.sum), max(tableb.geom)
FROM tablea
INNER JOIN tableb ON tablea.id = tableb.id
GROUP BY tableb.city
```